# You really want to help someone, but that individual becomes suspicious of the nature of your help and questions it

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms

I don’t know what to call the behavior of those who don’t believe that anybody acts with good intentions, so I'm looking for a suitable word, idiom or expression.

Comment: The first word I thought of was "cynical"

Comment: ... Yes. The OP's body question is somewhat different from the title question: general disposition or single instance? 'Cynical' is usually used for the prevailing mindset.

Answer (score 1):

For an adjective, try the British English term [**distrustful**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/distrustful) (or its British and American variant, **mistrustful**):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Feeling or showing distrust of someone or something:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *I have grown up to be distrustful of men*
>
> *Licinius became increasingly distrustful of him and suspicious of his own Christian subjects, whom he began to persecute.*
>
> *It is not in borrowers' interests for them to become worried and distrustful of their lender.*
>
> *Most Scots, they say, are distrustful of the nuclear industry and would prefer to tackle climate change through windmills, tidal and solar power, and recycling.*

The nouns from which the adjectival forms are derived are **distrust** and **mistrust**.

Another possible adjective is the one you yourself mentioned in the question title, namely [**suspicious:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/suspicious)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Having or showing a cautious distrust of someone or something:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *he was suspicious of her motives*
>
> *she gave him a suspicious look*
>
> *No wonder people are suspicious of politicians and the political process.*
>
> *In fact he was suspicious of any technological advance that might weaken the ‘master race’.*
>
> *She is suspicious of doctors and nurses and takes her medication only episodically.*

The noun from which the adjectival form is derived is **suspicion.**

(All definitions and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com.)

Answer (score 1):

A **skeptical person** would usually mistrust anything, anybody:

[Skepticism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skepticism):

> - a personal disposition toward doubt or incredulity of facts, persons, or institutions.
>
>   - I don't like your strong  skepticism about  politicians.
>   - The doctors still said they expected him to wake up any day, but Carmen was skeptical about how much they believed it.

(from TFD)

Comment: Note that the examples are of short(/ish)-term attitudes to individual situations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You are right..I changed a sentence.

Comment: Yes; you've one long-term, general situation and one [hopefully] shortish-term, particular situation example now.

Answer (score 0):

the mistrustful person is perhaps 'looking a gift horse in the mouth' (to determine if its age makes it a worthless gift)